# JavaScriptException when using DataTable.create() in JUnit with GWTTestCase

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, junit, datatable

For a school project, I have to test one of my classes. After writing and executing the test, I got the following error message and stacktrace:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (null)       
@com.google.gwt.visualization.client.DataTable::create()([]): null
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:249)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:576)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:284)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.visualization.client.DataTable$.create(DataTable.java)
at com.gwt.client.VizualizationManagerTest.gwtSetUp(VizualizationManagerTest.java:150)
...
```

From what I read, the problem is with the method: `DataTable.create()`, which creates a default `DataTable` that may later be filled with columns and rows.

I want to test if the data is being set up correctly. In my class, I am testing to verify that the initial data is being reformatted so that it can be used for `GWT Graphs`. So basically I take a very large `DataTable` and convert it into an `ArrayList` of smaller `DataTables`. But as far as I know, my test didn't even make it as far as testing that specific method, but got stuck in the: `@Before` method: `gwtSetUp()` on `DataTable.create()`.

Here is the code of my test:

```
package com.gwt.client;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.Random;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject;
import com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.DataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable.ColumnType;

public class VizualizationManagerTest extends GWTTestCase {
    @Test
    public void testPrepareData() {
        VisualizationManager.TableDATA = (DataTable) data;
        VisualizationManager.prepareData();
        assertEquals(data.getNumberOfColumns(), VisualizationManager.DATA.length);
        assertEquals(data.getNumberOfRows(), VisualizationManager.DATA[VisualizationManager.DATA.length-1].getNumberOfRows());

        //check all Cells for equality
        for (int i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns()-1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data.getNumberOfRows(); j++) {
                String test1 = VisualizationManager.DATA[i].getFormattedValue(j, 0);
                String tested1 = data.getFormattedValue(j, i+1);
                assertEquals(tested1, test1);
            }
        }
    }

    public AbstractDataTable data;

    @Before
    public void gwtSetUp() {
        DataTable mydata = DataTable.create();
        mydata.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Country");
        mydata.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "2011");
        mydata.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "2010");
        mydata.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "2009");
        mydata.addRows(5);
        mydata.setCell(0, 0, "Switzerland", "Switzerland", null);
        mydata.setCell(1, 0, "Germany", "Germany", null);
        mydata.setCell(2, 0, "Austria", "Austria", null);
        mydata.setCell(3, 0, "Slovakia", "Slovakia", null);
        mydata.setCell(4, 0, "Czech Republic", "Czech Republic", null);
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i=1; i<4; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {
                double number = random.nextDouble() % 1000.0;
                mydata.setCell(j, i, number, Double.toString(number), null);
            }
        }
        data = mydata;
    }

    @Override
    public String getModuleName() {
        return "com.gwt.AgrarAlpha_v1";
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find out how to fix the problem. I can't tell if it has to do with the set up of the whole test or just that I can't test with the class `DataTable`, or maybe something different...

I am using Eclipse Luna with Java 7 update 71 on OS X Yosemite (10.10).

Thank you for your help!!
Cheers, Romi

Comment: I tried to create a gwt graph without the test and other implementation... I got an exeption thrown: Cannot read property 'visualization' of undefined for the method DataTable.create()... I am starting to think that I can't use gwt graphs with java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with all GWT Visualization stuff (in the actual code and in JUnit and GWTtestCase) is that it needs to be reloaded on the web.
This means, that everything that has anything to do with GWT Visualization needs to be written the following way:

```
class Test extends GWTTestCase{
    @Test
    public void testSomething{
        Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ...
            }
        };

        VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, Table.PACKAGE);
    }
}
```